# Loading Images for Silverlight app from server without ssl

Tags: silverlight, ssl, cross-domain

I have an Silverlight application that uses ssl to communicate with the site-of-origin.  The application loads a number of images from a separate server (running apache under port 81 without ssl).  The images are regular png's.  The images from the Apache machine are not loaded properly, i.e. the image control remains blank.  When I post the same image on my app server (i.e. site-of-origin), and modify the link accordingly, the images are displayed properly.   [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) link on MSDN says that images are media are excluded from access-restriction policies.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Images may be exempt from Silverlight's cross domain policies, but that doesn't mean that the target server hasn't implemented its own anti-leeching functionality. Or you could have the URI of the images wrong. You should use the browser dev tools (IE Developer tools or Fiddler for Firefox) to view the request and the return.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are deploying your Silverlight application to a web server and not running it using the Visual Studio development server. I had a similar problem with images when I was using the built in development web server. You can find about my experience [here](http://nileshgule.blogspot.com/2011/06/ngtweet-part-5-big-bang-refactoring.html).

It might help if you subscribe to ImageFailed event and post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into cross-scheme access restrictions in silverlight, see table at the bottom of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189008(v=vs.95).aspx

One possible solution is to load image using WebClient and call SetSource on image element. That is what we do in our app. In fact we wraped it into custom image control that hides all annoying details.